# Very difficult to find the tasks with Due Date as empty and Status as completed. Any thoughts please?

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks, event, activities

I have so many activities created for one of my account. Some of the activities just do not have Due Date (empty) and Status as completed. When I tried to look for those activities in the account page (LEX) I have to click "Load More Past Activities" button/link several times (more than 15 times approx) to view those activities. Sales Reps have to waste more time in this.

The filter option that is available is of no use either to search for those activities that do not have a Due Date and Status as completed.

[image]

Please suggest if there is any shortcut or a way to find those activities. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of a solution are you looking for? You can certainly query on `ActivityDate = null AND Status = 'Completed'` in the Developer Console, or write a native report.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidReed. I am asking in the Account detail page on the right pane in Lightning Experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't customize the filter pane's behavior in the Lightning Activities view. You have to fit your data into their structure.

What you can do going forward is enforce invariants in your data to ensure that those filters are useful, like forcing the population of a Due Date. You can configure the publishers' field selection by editing their associated Global Action Layouts (or Object Action Layouts, if configured) in Setup, or apply validation rules to the Task and Event objects.

For past data, the only real option you have is to back-fill dates, identifying affected records by using a Salesforce report or querying something like `SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE ActivityDate = null AND Status = 'Completed'`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to pop-out the Activities in Account detail page as a separate view so that we can view all the activities just as we do with related lists in the account detail page?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's a standard component. Your options for customizing it are pretty much limited, as far as I am aware, to selecting global actions on the page layout and customizing the publishers' own layouts, not changing the overall behavior or UI.